# Tests are not updated in Visual Studio Test Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, test-explorer

`Test` output source within the `Output` tool window displays

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: Could not find testhost
```

and the list of tests in the `Test Explorer` tool window froze and do not refresh on any changes (build/rebuild), deleting `.vs` folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was caused by applying a version wildcard in central package version management in `Packages.props`

```
<PackageReference Update="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.6.*" />
```

which caused the version not to be resolved (`17.6.*` appeared in `Dependencies\Packages\Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk (17.6.*)` of a project)

so changing to

```
<PackageReference Update="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.6.0" />
```

fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Visual Studio 2022 Professional (Version 17.6.0). Installing Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk package solved this.